# Angular 6: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”)

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular 6 Project.
My code works fine when I run the command

> ng --serve

and also when I build it using

> ng build

and deploying it on my local Tomcat Server. I face no errors, works perfectly fine.

But when I deploy the same onto my Apache HTTPD server on my Ubuntu Machine, I face with the below error on Firefox and Chrome respectively

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: onfocusin attribute on DIV element.

Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP
compiler.js:22402

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP.
```

I've referred many links and tried multiple options, still unsuccessful in resolving it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Faced this same problem when deploying an ongoing Angular 6 development to an IIS server (while the application works perfect in local dev environment).

After some research, it looks that Webpack output is not dealing well with an strict Content-Security-Policy, so you have to reduce it.

This can be achieved by adding some custom header with the relaxed CSP definition.

In my case (IIS/ASP.NET)...

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Find some examples of how to add a custom CSP in Apache [here](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Update: Just as an additional info, refer to this [angular-cli issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3430).  There is mentioned by Clydin at Mar/19...

> **unsafe-eval** is no longer required if using a production build (with
>   the reflect polyfills removed as they are only needed for JIT).
>
> **unsafe-inline** is still required for styles. If that's not acceptable
>   for the project's requirements, the other option is to only use global
>   styles in the application and to not use any Angular libraries which
>   contain component styles. Note that the project will lose full
>   benefits of the component-based architecture under this scenario.

So, probably you can modify the CSP definition if using AOT.

Comment: Even with this github comment, still seems to be broken for me in my main bundle.